# Generics - Why are Class type variables not valid in static contexts?

Tags: java, generics

I am learning Java generics from a book. The book says that "Class Type Variables Are Not Valid in Static Contexts" and explains it with the following example.

Consider a generic class with type variables, such as Entry. You cannot use the type variables K and V with static variables or methods. For example, the following does not work:

```
public class Entry<K, V> {
    // Compiler error - V in static context ("Entry.this' cannot be referenced from a static context")
    private static V defaultValue;

    // Compiler error - V in static context ("Entry.this' cannot be referenced from a static context")
    public static void setDefault(V value) {
        defaultValue = value;
    }
}
```

After all, type erasure means there is only one such variable or method in the erased Entry class, and not one for each K and V.

I don't understand the above explanation. I tried to create the same code for K also and I got the same compile errors. Why is the above code illegal ?

Comment: An interesting note. You can pass the method `V` by adding it to the head. `public static <V> void setDefault(V value) { ... }`. Can't do it with the class variable, but the method will  take a generic reference then.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the question which the moderator has mentioned.

Comment: @JavaImpatient If you can explain why not, feel free to [edit] your question. If you can convince me, I can reopen the question for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Designers of Java generics chose to implement it using a mechanism called "type erasure". It means that generic specializations like `Entry<String,Integer>` and `Entry<Integer,String>` do not exist as separate classes. The type parameters are erased.

After you erase the type parameters from `Entry<String,Integer>` and `Entry<Integer,String>` you're left with just the `Entry` class.

If it were possible to have a static variable like `defaultValue` you would expect  `Entry<String,Integer>.defaultValue` to be a Integer. And you would expect  `Entry<Integer,String>.defaultValue` to be a String. But after type erasure only one `Entry` class with only one `defaultValue` variable, which now has to be both Integer and String. That's impossible. That's why you can't have a static variable of the generic type.

Answer (score 5):

Let's suppose `static` variables did work the way you described...

I would've been able to do:

```
Entry<String, Integer>.defaultValue = 1;
Entry<String, String>.defaultValue = "Hello";
System.out.println(Entry<String, Integer>.defaultValue); // 1
System.out.println(Entry<String, String>.defaultValue); // Hello
```

That's what you'd expect, isn't it?

But remember that `static` variables are *one per class*. Because of type erasure, `Entry<String, Integer>` and `Entry<String, String>` are considered the same class. And for the above code the work, `1` and `"Hello"` would need to be stored at *two* different places (two variables)!

Answer (score 3):

`V` will be the type of the instantiating class.  If two classes instantiate with different types for `V`, which type would be used to access the static field which is shared by all classes at the class level?

```
 private static V defaultValue;
```

Now one instantiated class has `V` as `String` and another has `V` as `Long`.

But static is available to **all** classes so which one would it be when accessed?

It's related as to why you can't reference an instance field from a static context.  Once inside a static context, which "instance" of the instance field would be accessed?  It can't be determined so it isn't legal (and doesn't make sense).